# 2-way trust between 2 server 2016 domains active, but unable to browse each others domains

Tags: domain, windows-server-2016, trust-relationship

Good afternoon, I have a 2 way transative trust between 2 domains, i have also validated them in the Active directory domains and trust tool, where they both show active.

From each domain controller i can ping the other domain controller by name and IP adres.

Also i have conditional forwarders on both dns'es

However, when I open up for instance the Domain users and computers tool on dc 1, i can only see its own domain, and not the trusted domain. I have also checked to see if the zone transfers are on in both dns'es and they are.

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was users Error. The 2 way trust is about sharing recourses, not about management, for that i would need a tree/child domain. In that last scenario enterprise admins can manage users etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch to the other domain in ADUC. It doesn't show up on it's own.

[image]

Comment: I was aware of that (I should have mentioned that of course), it doesn't show up in the tool at all, where i would switch to it, thats the problem.